# Name for functions with certain boundedness property

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces, terminology

Let $f: X_1 \rightarrow X_2 $ be a function between two metric spaces. My question is, if there is a name in the standard literature for the following property of $f$ in $x \in X_1$:

> $$(1)~~~~~~~~~~~ \forall \varepsilon > 0 ~~\exists \delta > 0 :~~\operatorname{im}_f(B_\varepsilon(x) ) \subseteq B_\delta(f(x))$$
>   i.e. the image of every $\varepsilon$-ball is bounded.

By looking for obvious candidates for a name, I only found the term of [,,local boundedness in $x$''](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_boundedness) which can in this case be expressed as
$$(2)~~~~~~~~~~~ \exists \varepsilon > 0 ~~\exists \delta > 0 :~~\operatorname{im}_{\vert f \vert}(B_\varepsilon(x) ) \subseteq B_\delta(0)$$
They are of course not equivalent, since the for example: the real function $f(x)=x^{-1}$ is locally bounded in every point $x \neq 0$ but does not have property $(1)$ in any point.

Comment: Is the $\delta$ mentioned global? That is, is the condition

$\forall\epsilon>0,\,\exists\delta>0,\,\forall x\in X_{1}\ldots$

the condition you are intending, or does that $\delta$ depend on $x$?

Comment: A consequence of your definition (regardless of whether or not the $\delta$ is global) is that if $f:X_{1}\rightarrow X_{2}$ is such a map then $f(X_{1})\subseteq B(f(x),\delta_{x})$ for every $x\in X_{1}$. Not sure if you want this or not.

Comment: @RobertThingum No, $\delta$ is not meant to be global. So the quantification was more intended to be $\forall x \in X_1 ~\forall \varepsilon ~\exists \delta ~...$, meanig $\delta = \delta(\varepsilon,x)$.

Comment: @RobertThingum I think $f(X_1) \subseteq B(f(x) , \delta_x)$ is only possible if $X_1$ is bounded. It doesn't work out in the example I gave, since $f(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} ) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} $.

Comment: Your functions look like bornologous functions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space#Bounded_maps

Comment: @RobertThingum Yes! This exactly fits what I was looking for; thank you very much! You can write up an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions satisfying $(1)$ are the functions sending metrically bounded sets of $X_{1}$ to metrically bounded sets of $X_{2}$.

See the following

[Bornological Space on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space)

If you are interesting in reading about some applications of these kinds of functions within an active area of research you should look into coarse geometry.

[Coarse Spaces on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarse_structure)

Comment: Is it right to say $f$ preserves metrically bounded sets?

Comment: I would say so. You could also say that $f$ simply preserves "boundedness".